# How get user's IP Address (Mobile Network or Wi-Fi)? -Android/java

Tags: java, android, ip

After visiting multiple question on same topic.
This is not duplicate Question. Because all other provided code is old or deprecated.

I want to check What is IP address of user when splash screen show. No matter that time connected Mobile data or Wi-Fi.

> **Method**: through `WifiManager` .
>
> **Issue:1)** It provide IP only when user connected to wifi. **2)** `Formatter.formatIpAddress` deprecated in API version 12. **3)**  `getHostAddress()`, which supports both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. This method does not support IPv6 addresses

**I found only one short solution is just call this Api, http://www.ip-api.com/json <and get data through Json.**

Is there any other way to get IP from android device?

Comment: why exactly would you want to check someone's ip?

Comment: You need to be more precise. *Which* IP address do you want? For example, your `WifiManager` solution would provide the actual IP address assigned to the device, but typically that will be a **private** IP address on the local network. The `ip-api.com` solution will provide the **public** IP address of that network as it appears on the Internet.

Comment: there is also another method to get the ipadress using NetworkInterface but it returns null when the user isn't connected to any ip address.

Comment: @CommonsWare I want to use this IP for detect country of user. And visible some extra content according to their country (for few countries). [Which method you prefer for this? If any imported phone in any other country?]

Comment: @TexD: I went through this process earlier this year. Free geolocation services are very unreliable. Commercial ones are better. However, any decent geolocation service will handle finding the IP address for you -- you do not need any code in your app for that. The IP address of relevance would be the public IP address, not the private one like you might get from `WifiManager`.

Answer (score -1):

```
fun getIPAddress(): String? {
    try {
        val interfaces: List<NetworkInterface> = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces().toList()
        for (networkInterface in interfaces) {
            val addresses: List<InetAddress> = networkInterface.inetAddresses.toList()
            for (address in addresses) {
                if (!address.isLoopbackAddress && !address.isLinkLocalAddress && address.isSiteLocalAddress) {
                    return address.hostAddress
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}
```

It filters out loopback, link-local, and non-site-local addresses to find the IP address of the device. The function returns the IP address as a String, or null if it fails to retrieve the IP address.